# How do I dynamically update matplotlib plots in a tqdm-loop inside a Jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, data-analysis, tqdm

How do I do something like:

```
from tqdm.notebook import tqdm
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from IPython import display

import time
import numpy as np

xx = list()

for i in tqdm(range(500)):
    xx.append(i * 0.1)
    yy = np.sin(xx)

    if i % 10 == 0:
        display.clear_output(wait=True)
        plt.plot(xx, yy)
        time.sleep(0.1)
```

but keeping a `tqdm` progress bar from disappearing when I update the plot?

Comment: Can you delete the line `display.clear_output(wait=True)` ? Or is this not what you want?

Comment: @DerekO Then I get many plots with incremental changes rather than a single plot that gets updated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be done by getting a display handle and then updating it, rather than clearing the display in each iteration.

```
from tqdm.notebook import tqdm
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from IPython import display

import time
import numpy as np

xx = list()

# display the initial figure and get a display handle
# (it starts out blank here)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
dh = display.display(fig, display_id=True)

for i in tqdm(range(500)):
    xx.append(i * 0.1)
    yy = np.sin(xx)

    if i % 10 == 0:
        # generate the plot and then update the
        # display handle to refresh it
        ax.plot(xx, yy)
        dh.update(fig)
        time.sleep(0.1)

# close the figure at the end or else you
# end up with an extra plot
plt.close()
```

Comment: If you add `ax.clear()` right before the `ax.plot`, there will be only one plot (i.e. the line color will remain consistent during plotting and the line will be smoother). Additionally, the `display` function is often present in Jupyter environments so `from IPython.display import display` is more consistent with the common usage.